# Display Static WebPage on ChromeCast

Tags: javascript, android, html, chromecast

I've been looking over the ChromeCast SDK, and it all seems pretty manageable.

The only unfortunate thing I've seen is that it seems it's only meant for casting video, audio or images. You can send a URL, but the URL has to be that of one of the aforementioned types.

I've written an HTML5 "dashboard" type of display for my app which updates using AJAX, and I'd love to be able to launch the dashboard via ChromeCast. This would equate to signaling ChromeCast to load an external URL that is available over the internet, and then ChromeCast would load the URL (preferably without any browser chrome).

In a nutshell, I'd like to hit the ChromeCast button, select the ChromeCast device, and then the device would load a url like "http://www.google.com" and my TV would just display the google home page.

I'm not worried about scrolling, zooming, or any interactivity... it's literally a bunch of analytics that update as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a Custom Receiver. They allow you to just load in a webpage instead of using the default players.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver

Comment: Awesome! I must have missed this section. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No worries. Everyone overlooks things.